# How to create a column with all the values in a range given by another column in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a problem with the following scenario using PySpark version 2.0, I have a DataFrame with a column contains an array with start and end value, e.g. 
`[1000, 1010]`

I would like to know how to create and compute another column which contains an array that holds all the values for the given range? the result of the generated range values column will be:

```
    +--------------+-------------+-----------------------------+
    |   Description|     Accounts|                        Range|
    +--------------+-------------+-----------------------------+
    |       Range 1|   [101, 105]|    [101, 102, 103, 104, 105]|
    |       Range 2|   [200, 203]|         [200, 201, 202, 203]|
    +--------------+-------------+-----------------------------+
```

Comment: I have the same requirement which is answered in the below link but in need the code in pyspark
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48073101/how-to-create-a-column-with-all-the-values-in-a-range-given-by-another-column

Comment: Can you please add the output of `df.printschema` directly to your question().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

## define the udf

```
def range_value(a):
    start = a[0]
     end = a[1] +1 
     return list(range(start,end))

from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import types as pt

df = spark.createDataFrame([("Range 1", list([101,105])), ("Range 2", list([200, 203]))],("Description", "Accounts"))

range_value= F.udf(range_value, pt.ArrayType(pt.IntegerType()))
df = df.withColumn('Range', range_value(F.col('Accounts')))
```

Output

[image]

Comment: to make end value display in range, we need to add +1 to end parameter in the function definition. i.e.end = a[1]+1

Answer (score 0):

you should use UDF [(UDF sample)](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/udf-python.html)
Consider your pyspark data frame name is df, your data frame could be like this:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
[("Range 1", list([101,105])), 
 ("Range 2", list([200, 203]))],
("Description", "Accounts"))
```

And your solution is like this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import numpy as np

def make_range_number(arr):
    number_range = np.arange(arr[0], arr[1]+1, 1).tolist()
    return number_range

range_udf = F.udf(make_range_number)

df = df.withColumn("Range", range_udf(F.col("Accounts")))
```

Have a fun time!:)

Comment: I have executed it in the above way, but it is giving module error like below.
"ImportError: ('No module named numpy', <function subimport at 0x7fc598cb31b8>, ('numpy',))"

Comment: numpy is a python module, you have to install it